# printing a '£' symbol using esc_pos_printer wifi thermal printer plugin in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, thermal-printer

I am unable to print '£' symbol on my printer. For example when I use:

```
PosColumn(text: '- £${(order.total).toStringAsFixed(2)}', width: 2, styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.right)),
```

But it doesn't print '£'. Any pointers please?

Comment: does the plugin support the euro symbol ?

Comment: Isn't it necessary to specify the code page in the `codeTable` of `PosStyles` of `styles` when creating print data? [Generate a Receipt](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer#generate-a-receipt)

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out, the library does support '£' symbol and many others!

The codeTable which supports '£' symbol is CP1250.

---

If someone lands on this page in future stuck with a similar problem - Do the following:

```
  printer.text('£', styles: PosStyles(codeTable: 'CP1250')
```

Execute the above line by changing the codeTable. You will soon learn which codeTable was successful in printing your symbol. Just use that!

Comment: Is there any way to print arabic letters